# String getBytes ISO-8859-1 'ü' bug chars after 'ü' missing

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

String.getBytes seems not to work for the village with name 'Oberbüren':

```
@Test
public void getBytes_buggy() throws Exception {
    // all chars after 'ü' are missing
    final String actual = new String("Oberbüren".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    assertEquals("Oberb�", actual);
}

@Test
public void getBytes_working() throws Exception {
    // with 4 chars after 'ü' it works
    final String actual = new String("Oberbüren12".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    assertEquals("Oberb�ren12", actual);
}
```

Funny as it is, it works with 'ä', 'ö' and when you have 5 or more characters after the 'ü'!

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know about `assertEquals` but should the first one be `assertEquals("Oberb�ren", actual);` instead of `assertEquals("Oberb�", actual);`?

Comment: `String("Oberbüren".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))` this is a junk operation: UTF-16 to ISO-8859-1; then pretend the bytes are platform encoding back to UTF-16. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: you're right: it should not be equal! but it is! both tests are green and the first shouldn't be!

Comment: I expect in the first test: 
assertEquals("Oberb�ren", actual);

Comment: In general, if the problem is either in your code or in an old system method in Java, assume that the bug is in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test the bytes returned by `getBytes` then you should test them directly, not by converting them back into another string.

```
byte[] actual = "Oberbüren".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] expected = new byte[] { 0x4f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x72, 0x62, 0xfc, ....};
assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

The single-argument String constructor always uses the platform default encoding to decode bytes to characters, you should always prefer the two-argument version where you can specify the correct encoding explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to convert to UTF-8, but this test also does work (but shouldn't):  
`@Test  
public void getBytes_buggy() throws Exception {  
    final byte[] iso8859bytes = "Oberbüren".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");  
    final String actual = new String(iso8859bytes, "UTF-8");  
    assertEquals("Oberb�", actual);  
}`

Comment: @user3645086 that clearly won't work because you're taking bytes that you know are ISO-8859-1 and telling the String constructor to process them as if they were UTF-8.  If you have ISO-8859-1 bytes and want to turn them into a string then you have to tell the string constructor to use ISO-8859-1.  If you have a Java string and you want the bytes in UTF-8 then ask for `getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: @user3645086 `assertEquals("Oberb\u00fcren", new String(iso8859bytes, "ISO-8859-1"))` (to remove any ambiguity around what character encoding the source code of the test is written in).